# Exercício da água e dos garrafões

Tags: python

"Suponha que tem uma certa quantidade de garrafas vazias com capacidade de 5, 1.5, 0.5 e 0.25 litros. Admita que tem um número ilimitado de garrafas de cada tipo.

Dada uma certa quantidade de água que pretende guardar em garrafas, como resolver o problema minimizando o número de garrafas a usar?
Como poderia utilizar o computador para lhe calcular o número necessário de de cada tipo de garrafa?"

```
def agua(l):
  totalgarrafas= 0
  garrafa = 5
  while True:
    if l>=garrafa:
        l-=garrafa
        totalgarrafa+=1
    else:
        if totalgarrafa>0:
            print(f'O numero de garrafas é {totalgarrafa} por {garrafa} garrafas')
        if garrafa==5:
            garrafa=1.5
        elif garrafa==1.5:
            garrafa=0.5
        elif garrafa==0.5:
            garrafa=0.25
        totalgarrafa=0
        if totalgarrafa==0:
            break
print('Volte Sempre')
```

Comment: Boa tarde Rodrigo! Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow! É uma boa prática que, além de postar o código, você explique especificamente o problema que está tendo.

Comment: Não consigo chegar a solução do problema, a função que fiz não dá, falta me algo.:(

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta especificando o seu problema, uma mensagem de erro seria um bom começo. aproveitando o momento, seria legal dar uma olhada nesse tópico de [como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/138733) além do tópico de [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me permite, eu gostaria de pontuar duas coisas:

1 - O seu código não parecia fazer muito sentido, então eu reescrevi do zero.

2 - Admito que existe certa verborragia no código que escrevi, mas foi para fins didáticos.

Segue abaixo:

```
'''
garrafas com capacidade de apenas 5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.25
entra x agua e se autodistribui em n garrafas, da maior para a menor

'''
#OBS: a divisão inteira do Python (x//y)retorna apenas a parte inteira do quociente, ignorando os decimais pós-vírgula.

#para melhor compreensão, vou explicar o que a linha faz acima da mesma, ok? =D

#declara a função numeroGarrafas que recebe um parâmetro litros_agua.
def numeroGarrafas(litros_agua):

    #copiamos o valor da variável/parâmetro litros_agua para total_agua. Dispensável, mas didático.
    total_agua = litros_agua 

    #divisão inteira por 5 (24.3//5=4)
    cinco_litros = litros_agua//5 

    #subtrai do valor total a quantidade que se conseguiu armazenar em garrafas de 5L
    #equivale a: litros_agua = litros_agua - cinco_litros*5 (litros_agua = 24.3-(4*5) = 24.3-20 = 4.3)
    litros_agua -=(cinco_litros*5) 

    #mesmo procedimento, mas com valores de 1.5
    #litro_e_meio = 4.3//1.5 = 2
    litro_e_meio = litros_agua//1.5

    #litros_agua = 4.3-2*1.5 = 4.3-3 = 1.3
    litros_agua -=(litro_e_meio*1.5)

    #agora com 0.5
    #meio_litro = 1.3//0.5 = 2
    meio_litro = litros_agua//0.5

    #litros_agua = 1.3 - 2*0.5 = 1.3-1 = 0.3
    litros_agua-=(meio_litro*0.5)

    #quarto_de_litro = 0.3//0.25 = 1
    quarto_de_litro = litros_agua//0.25

    #litros_agua = 0.3-1*0.25 = 0.3-0.25 = 0.05 [ou 50ml]
    litros_agua -=(quarto_de_litro*0.25)

    #para não desperdiçarmos o máximo de 0.24L, vamos incluir uma linha com condicionais abaixo:
    #se sobrar alguma agua, reservamos a menor garrafa disponível para contê-la.
    if(litros_agua>0):
        #equivale a quarto_de_litro = quarto_de_litro+1
        quarto_de_litro+=1

    #finalmente o print, que coloca as variaveis conforme a própria disposição da frase.
    print('total:',total_agua,' garrafas de 5L:',cinco_litros,' de 1.5L:',\
        litro_e_meio,' de 0.5L:',meio_litro,' e de 0.25L:',quarto_de_litro)
   #a string acima te dá os resultados, do maior para o menor, mais a quantidade total de litros(para efeito de referência)

numeroGarrafas(24.3) #a saida deve ser (total: 24.3  garrafas de 5L: 4.0  de 1.5L: 2.0  de 0.5L: 2.0  e de 0.25L: 1.0)
```

Comment: Fico agradecido pela resposta. Mas fiquei com algumas duvidas, que peço desculpa estar a perguntar, mas ainda estou no inicio.  Qual a razão de pormos total_agua=litros_agua. Como o python consegue calcular o resultado se não foi usado if ou while?

Comment: Editei a solução para explicar melhor, blz? @RodrigoFerreira